# Deploying a Spring web application on a vSphere environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vmware, vsphere

I have to deploy a Spring application on one company's internal server. The server runs several VMs over VMWare vsphere, and i was wondering what's the best approach and what can be used to deploy my Java Spring application.

My two ideas were:

- Using one of the Windows Server instances and run it as a service everytime the instance gets started. (Probably the easiest but not the best).
- Finding a way to deploy a Java runtime somehow as a virtual machine, in order just to have my instance of Spring boot running over there.

Unfortunately my application, for its purpose and the way it works, needs to be deployed over the local area network (my application polls data from LAN IoT clients and it needs to be inside of our network), therefore i cannot use any online service like AWS or Google.

I would like to know if my option number 2 is a viable option and what can be used to achieve it (in terms of software needed and if it's worth the effort). Unfortunately i have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply run a JVM in a virtual machine. VMs require an OS to be installed first and then running the JVM as a process inside it. Essentially running a spring boot app on a VM is the same as running it on a physical machine in terms of software stack requirements. You're not forced to use Windows for the OS but it's up to your preferences and company's policy. A minimal Linux distro can reduce the amount of resources needed by the VM significantly so that the spring-boot app is the predominant resource hog.

It is not a good practice to use existing VMs to run a new unrelated service (I assume you've been running other servers there). The main value of VMs is that they can be isolated from one another and therefore not affecting each other's stability while still benefiting from being co-located on the same physical hardware. They can be migrated between physical hosts **while running** (vMotion/DRS) and restarted automatically in case of failure (vSphere HA).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! My doubt was in fact if there's an existing environment already (for example a Docker environment) that doesn't require an OS "lower layer" and that can run directly over vmware, but if i understand correctly you just confirmed that it's not possible. The request came by looking at web services like AWS where on elastic beanstalk you can create runnable instances of a Java environment with certain resources assigned, and that i wrongly supposed it wasn't strictly running on a Windows or Linux OS

Comment: Actually Project Pacific or vSphere with Tanzu / Kubernetes 7 can actually support native kubernetes on the hypervisors. For previous versions you can always set up a kubernetes cluster on an underlying vSphere cluster using VMs as the k8s nodes. There are a lot of solutions that can automate this e.g. Pivotal Container / K8s Services.